# MongoDb update with ElemMatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a collection that has document structure like following:

[Mongo PlayGround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iFLj8VXfVeF)

```
{
    "basicDetails": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "xyz"
    },
    "tasks": [{
        "id": "10",
        "name": "task10",
        "subtasks": [{
            "id": "120",
            "name": "subTask120",
            "description": "ABC"
        }]
    }]
}
```

As you can see, each document has basicDetails object and a tasks array. Each task contains  some properties of its own and a subtasks array.

I want to update subtasks's description from `ABC` to `XYZ`

`where root level id is 1, task'id is 10 and  subTasks.id =120`

How do I do so?

I know I could find correct document via:

```
db.collection.find({
  "basicDetails.id": "1",
  "tasks": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "id": "10",
      "subtasks": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "id": "120"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

But how do I update it? I want to update only one single property of a single subtasks i.e description

Comment: What did you try? 
BTW I can recommend some 101 from Mongo University.

Comment: @A.D. `db.Projects.updateOne({"basicDetails.id":"200" , "tasks":{"$elemMatch":{"basicDetails.id":"139","subtasks":{"$elemMatch":{"name":"xyz3"} }}}  },
{$set: {'basicDetails.$.tasks.basicDetails': 'Blah'}} 
)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update nested arrays, the filtered positional operator $[[identifier]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) identifies the array elements that match the `arrayFilters` conditions for an update operation.

Try the following query to `$set` in nested array:

```
db.collection.updateOne({
  "basicDetails.id": "1"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "tasks.$[tasks].subtasks.$[subtasks].description": "XYZ"
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "tasks.id": "10"
    },
    {
      "subtasks.id": "120"
    }
  ]
})
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ciPFC5U8zrP)

Comment: Isn't update() deprecated? Can this be done with UpdateOne()? Or UpdateMany()?